# Yii2 composer update on windows too long

Tags: windows, angularjs, composer-php, yii2

I'm new to composer and Yii2. Already installed yii2 on Windows and now I need to install new bower dependency called bower-asset/angular-material. Added `"bower-asset/angular-material": "0.4.2"` to composer.json require block and run `composer update bower-asset/angular-material`. It takes too long time (about 1 hour). Somehow composer read all patches of angular

```
Reading bower.json of bower-asset/angular (v1.3.0-patch2531)
Reading bower.json of bower-asset/angular (v1.3.0-patch2530)
Reading bower.json of bower-asset/angular (v1.3.0-patch2529)
...
```

Why it takes too long time? What I need to do?

Comment: I had the same issue and I have fixed it from here: https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/issues/227#issuecomment-225656259

Answer (score 3):

#### fxp/composer-asset-plugin >= v1.3:

To skip reading `-patch` packages, you need just added to `composer.json` of your project follow config of `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`:

```json
"config": {
    "fxp-asset": {
        "pattern-skip-version": "(-build|-patch)"
    }
}
```

Note: also this meaning the `-build` packages also will be skipped.

#### fxp/composer-asset-plugin < v1.3:

If you are using `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` older than version 1.3, you can use follow config:

```json
"extra": {
    "asset-pattern-skip-version": "(-build|-patch)"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

Make sure you are running the latest version of Bower. I am currently running v1.2.6 and null works to fetch the latest dependency.

**$ bower -v**

If you have installed bower globally via npm, then you can update it this way:

**$ npm update bower -g**

Note: you may need to run that as sudo depending on your file permissions.

Hope this helps.